# Modifying XML using JDOM

Tags: java, xml, dtd, jdom-2

I'm trying to modify an XML document with JDOM, the problem is that does not change anything in the file.

I've been searching the internet to modify the file and in any site explains how to save the file.

I would like you to tell me what I do wrong or or if there is another way.

Method code is:

```
public void ocuparPlazaParking(){

        //Se crea un SAXBuilder para poder parsear el archivo
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        File xmlFile = new File( "C:/Users/Alejandro/Parking/parking.xml");

        try
        {       
            Document document = (Document) builder.build( xmlFile );

            //Se obtiene la raiz 'parking'
            Element elementoParking = document.getRootElement();


            //Obtengo las plantas
            List listadePlantas =  elementoParking.getChildren( "planta" );
            for ( int i=0; i < listadePlantas.size(); i++ ){

                Element elementoPlanta = (Element) listadePlantas.get(i);       

                //Obtengo las filas
                List listadeFilas =  elementoPlanta.getChildren( "fila" );
                for ( int j = 0; j < listadeFilas.size(); j++ ){
                    //obtengo la fila
                    Element elementoFila = (Element) listadeFilas.get(j);           


                    //Obtengo los bloques

                    List listadeBloques =  elementoFila.getChildren( "bloque" );
                    for ( int k = 0; k < listadeBloques.size(); k++ ) {

                        Element elementoBloque = (Element) listadeBloques.get(k);


                        List listadeElementos =  elementoBloque.getChildren( "elemento" );
                        for ( int l = 0; l < listadeElementos.size(); l++ ){
                            Element elementoElemento = (Element) listadeElementos.get(l);

                            if(elementoElemento.getChildText("numero").equals("1003")){

                                elementoElemento.getChild("estado").setText("ocupada");
                            }

                        }    
                    }   
                }
            }  
        }

        catch ( IOException io ) {
            System.out.println( io.getMessage() );
        }catch ( JDOMException jdomex ) {
            System.out.println( jdomex.getMessage() );
        }           
    }
```

And the DTD of the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT parking (planta+)>
<!ATTLIST parking nombreParking CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST parking direccion CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST parking poblacion CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST parking pais CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT planta (fila+)>
<!ATTLIST planta numPlazas CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST planta numeroPlanta CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST planta tamano CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT fila (bloque+)>
<!ATTLIST fila altoFila CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST fila anchoFila CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT bloque (elemento+)>
<!ATTLIST bloque anchoBloque CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT elemento (tipo,subtipo,estado,posicion,longitud,numero)>
<!ELEMENT tipo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT subtipo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT estado (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT longitud (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT posicion (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT numero (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: You are reading the xml file into a DOM and modifying the DOM. I don't see where you are writing the modified DOM back to the file. Are you actually changing the file at some point?

Comment: i do not know how to save changes to the same xml

Comment: @prabugp - note that the user is loading in to JDOM, not DOM ... b ut, you are right that its' not being saved back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andy has suggested the right solution, but for the wrong technology.

You are loading the XML document in to the JDOM in-memory model. You are changing the content in the memory model, but you are not writing the model back to disk.... and for that yous should [use XMLOutputter](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html)

You will want to add the following:

```
XMLOutputter xmlout = new XMLOutputter();
try (FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Alejandro/Parking/parking.MODIFIED.xml")) {
    xmlout.output(document, fileout);
}
```

Also, your tag indicates that you are using JDOM2. In this case, you should be using Generics-enabled Lists... so your code should look like (note the lack of casting...):

> ```
>         //Obtengo las plantas
>         List listadePlantas =  elementoParking.getChildren( "planta" );
>         for ( int i=0; i < listadePlantas.size(); i++ ){
>
>             Element elementoPlanta = (Element) listadePlantas.get(i);
> ```

Should/could be:

```
        //Obtengo las plantas
        for (Element elementoPlanta : elementoParking.getChildren( "planta" )){
```

(are you importing `org.jdom.Element` or `org.jdom2.*` ... ?)

Also, in your post you indicate that you searched the internet .... The top-three results for [Google Searching 'JDOM Save File'](https://www.google.ca/#hl=en&q=JDOM%20save%20file) are all good, but recently a [complete tutorial was put together](http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/jdom2/java-xml-jdom2-introduction.jsp), and it has a [section dedicated to the XMLOutputter](http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/jdom2/java-xml-jdom2-Outputter.jsp)